# Adding Date+Time without 12AM moving to the next day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am using the attached to automate a time entry to go along with the date for a calendar import. The entries don't have times, and the staff will not enter them try as I might. I need to automate them to simplify the entry procedure.

The issue I am facing is that the Calendar API needs the data to be in DATE/TIME format. To do this I need to use the =DATE+TIME formula. When I do so and the time reaches 12:00AM, the dates thereafter change to the following day.

Essentially I need to either override the logic that makes it move into the next day after midnight appears, or I need to tell either the function in column B-C that it can never roll to midnight. I am trying to think of perhaps a way that I can tell the function to reset the time if the date in column A changes to a new day, and if it doesn't change to a new day go ahead and use the existing function and add 5 minutes to the time that is shown previously to it.

I am stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is a sheet to show you the issue](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mPTJ7DYEUlPDIiSnohrDWQ53rgJb5BhmXAK1HujIhUg/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the formula I tried, which worked to sort out the problem but did not work with the Calendar API requirements to format at DATE/TIME. Even when using the importrange formula to move the data into a new sheet with the cells formatted as DATE/TIME it still recognizes it as TEXT as this is what the formula prescribes.

=IF(A2<>"",(CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2,"MM/DD/YYYY")&" "&TEXT(B2,"HH:MM:SS"))),"")

I need this to work in both the sheet and in the import to Calendar using the Calendar API requirements through APPScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, here a suggestion with a custom Apps Script function called like a normal Google Sheet function.

- Open Apps Script Editor and paste the function below
- Call the function `rebuildDateTime(COL1, COL2)` inside your spreadsheet

Spreadsheet:

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet with custom formula]

Code:

```
function rebuildDateTime(arg0, arg1) {

  var date = new Date(arg0);
  var str = arg1.toString().split(':');
  date.setHours(str[0]);
  date.setMinutes(str[1]);

  return date;
}
```

**Warning :**

- Your COL2 (which contains only the time), must be forced to TEXT FORMAT

**References :**

- [Create a custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=fr)

Comment: When I attempt to apply your solution I am getting the following error: 10:11:48 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
rebuildDateTime @ Code.gs:4

Comment: Also, in the sheet that I will be applying this solution, just to give more information, I already have script to autofill as well. It is likely the error with the toScript that is causing the #ERROR in my spreadsheet, but I am getting that back when running the autofill code currently as well. I will update the attached spreadsheet with the full code so that you can see it.

Comment: @TanyaVanderVecht, you are getting this error because the COL2 is not set to TEXT FORMAT. About ```I am getting that back when running the autofill code currently as well```, could you please clarify

Comment: I have set up the COL2 in Plain Text format. I am still receiving the following error in Appscript which is causing a #ERROR in the spreadsheet.: 10:03:44 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
rebuildDateTime @ Code.gs:44                                                                                                   I have added the function and edited the autofill3 and autofill4 functions in AppScript to contain the Excel/Sheets function you show above so you can see the issue. The link is above in the initial post.

Comment: I think the issue is occurring because autofill1 and autofill2 contain a TIME calculation. I need the times in COL2 and COL3 to auto-calculate a new time. I am unsure how to do this without using that formula. COL2 for example formatted as text shows 9:00:00, how do I add 15 minutes or 30 minutes for example to this in COL3 without it being treated as time.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments :) I am still learning, and I figured this out. I needed to add 2 more columns that autofill with the following formula =IF(A2<>"",(TEXT(B2,"HH:MM:SS")),"") to allow me to use the TIME based formula to perform the calculation in COL2 and COL3, then convert those solutions to TEXT in COL4 and COL5. I then just need to set up an additional autofill for those columns and all should be well. THANK YOU! For your help, it is MUCH appreciated!!

Comment: @TanyaVanderVecht Sorry for the delay, if I understand what you said there was a format problem with another apps script function ? Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution with those functions, and even better if my solution bring something. Please mark your question as answered if it's the case ;)

Comment: Sorry for the massive delay in my response. I have been nursing this sheet for a month now and some days it works, some days it doesn't, and I do not know why. The script you provided when it is not working gives me the following error; I cannot figure out why it is though. 7:38:16 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
rebuildDateTime @ Code.gs:103

Comment: I love when it is simple. I figured it out. I will close this after but I thought I would respond. The Date Format somehow was being kicked out in the imported range that brings the dates into the editing sheet. Once I reset it, everything works fine.